# Redundancy in formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formula

I'm debugging a large spreadsheet and I've come across the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF($B37="CMD Account Team",
            VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B37,
                                G37,
                                F37),
                    lists!$B:$C,
                    2,
                    FALSE),
         IF('INPUT - Project Costs'!B37="ITS",
            VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE('INPUT - Project Costs'!B37,
                                'INPUT - Project Costs'!G37,
                                'INPUT - Project Costs'!F37),
                    'ITS Rates'!B:F, 
                    5,
                    FALSE)*7.5,
            0)),
         0)
```

The interesting part is:

```
            VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE('INPUT - Project Costs'!B37,
                                'INPUT - Project Costs'!G37,
                                'INPUT - Project Costs'!F37),
```

Considering that this formula is already located on the 'INPUT - Project Costs' sheet, why would the original author from way back when feel the need to be so explicit when referencing the cells? The **really** confusing thing for me is that earlier in the formula the author did the exact same thing but *left out* the explicit sheet reference:

```
            VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B37,
                                G37,
                                F37),
```

I'm new to excel sorcery, and would love to hear from someone who has had more experience and can propose possible reasons as to why this formula is the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when you start writing the formula, click on another tab, then click back on the original tab. Either way should yield the same result.